# send messages from the main process to renderer process in Electron don't work

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm playing with Electron for the first time and trying to send a message from the main process to the renderer process. But it doesn't work.

Here's the necessary code:

**main.js**

```js
function getFolderContent(folderPath) {
  if (folderPath === undefined) {
    folderPath = store.get('path.lastOpenFolder')
  }

  try {
    const subfolders = fs.readdirSync(folderPath, { withFileTypes: true });
    const folderNames = subfolders
      .filter((item) => item.isDirectory())

    return folderNames;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return [];
  }
}

const createWindow = () => {
  //...

  const folderNames = getFolderContent();
  // console.log('folderNames', folderNames);
  mainWindow.webContents.send('initFolderContent', folderNames)
}
```

The `folderNames` has already been proven to have the correct values with `// console.log('folderNames', folderNames);`.

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  getFolderContent: () => ipcRenderer.invoke('getFolderContent'),
  initFolderContent: (callback) => ipcRenderer.on('initFolderContent', callback),
})
```

**renderer.js**

```js
window.electronAPI.initFolderContent((_event, folderNames) => {
  console.log('------------')
  console.log(folderNames)
})
```

`window.electronAPI.initFolderContent` in renderer.js has no console output, even after the message has been sent by `mainWindow.webContents.send('initFolderContent', folderNames)`. `window.electronAPI.initFolderContent` looks like it didn't receive the message, so it wasn't executed. The issue might be with the configuration in `preload.js`.

I want to send messages from the main process to renderer process using `contextBridge`, and successfully receiving `folderNames` in render.js.

Comment: Have you checked for error in the **dev** console? Where is `getFolderContent` `handle`?

Comment: No output in the console.

`//console.log('folderNames', folderNames);` in main.js. has proven that folderNames has a value. So it can be reasonably concluded that it's unrelated to `getFolderContent`. 

The only issue is `window.electronAPI.initFolderContent` in renderer.js has no console output, even after the message has been sent by `mainWindow.webContents.send('initFolderContent', folderNames)`. `window.electronAPI.initFolderContent` looks like it didn't receive the message, so it wasn't executed.

And I have changed the question to add getFolderContent you wanted.

Comment: I meant the `getFolderContent`'s `handle` coming with the `invoke` in your preload. With the code you shared it looks like you send the `initFolderContent` message before your renderer is ready to receive.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I misunderstood. However, this function is not important; it's for another feature and workwell.

Comment: Then make sure you renderer is ready before using `send`.

Comment: It sounds like the reason, but I don't know how to confirm that the render is ready. The variable `mainWindow` only in `createWindow`.  In specific, what should I do to send meaasge?

Comment: Look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-sender

Comment: I used `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)` in render.js to trigger `getFolderContent` in main.js with a new handle and get the list when the app opens. The issue is exactly what you mentioned: **the renderer isn't ready before using send.** Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This tool looks great, but is there a native way to confirm that the renderer is ready and then have the main process send a message?

Comment: @Arkellys Yes, I got the solution. Thank you!!!

Comment: I think you can mark this question as duplicate then.